# I had an install error and all of the default layout/class files are missing. How do I fix this?

Tags: lyx, installing, lyx-layouts

During the installation process there was an error and it seems that none of the default class layouts are available. I have tried looking at the LyX wiki but it seems that only user made layouts are available there. Is there somewhere I can download all of the layouts and a zip file or similar.

As an added complication, the computer I am using is from Japan and I don't understand what is happening during the install procedure, and some of the error dialogs are in Japanese.

Thanks.

Edit: Further Information: Due to my work internet settings, I was not able to update Miktek during the installation.

Edit 2 log file extracts:

```
problem: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-core-PS.dll does not exist
problem: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-core.dll does not exist
problem: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-packagemanager-PS.dll does not exist
problem: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\miktex/bin\MiKTeX209-packagemanager.dll does not exist

An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp
  source line: 305
  message: The operation failed for some reason.
  info: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\miktex/bin\initexmf.exe
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Sorry about your computer problems. LyX is a front-end for a TeX distribution. Please tell us which TeX distribution and which operating system is installed on your computer.

Comment: If LaTeX is installed correctly, in LyX going to Tools > Reconfigure might help. What OS are you using? Which LaTeX package manager?

Comment: @Mico & Scottkosty: I am using Windows 8, so I guess I'm getting Tex through Miktek 2.9. Reconfigure didn't work. Also, added more info in the original post.

Comment: I would suggest uninstalling everything, installing MiKTeX separately (that is, not through LyX), and then installing LyX.

Comment: I uninstalled everything and tried to reinstall. Now it fails to install Lyx at all, it fails during the Miktex installation. I've added an extract of the log files in the original post.